# CMake: Generate a jar file using multiple jar dependencies (out of source build)

Tags: java, cmake

I have spent a few days now to do the following with CMake (3.5.2). Using an out of source build, create a jar file relying on multiple external jar dependencies. In my manifest, I want only to specify Main-Class, nothing else.

This is what I have in my *croco/owl2gdb/CMakeLists.txt* directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)

include(UseJava)

project (owl2gdb)

SET(CLASSPATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/HermiT.jar)

list(APPEND CMAKE_JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH ${CLASSPATH})

SET(SOURCE
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/owl2gdb/OWL2GDB.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/graphdatabase/GraphDatabase.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/CPPFileWriter.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/CppHeaderFileWriter.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/CppSourceFileWriter.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/CppTextTemplate.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/GraphDatabaseHeaderWriter.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/GraphDatabaseSourceWriter.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/knowledge/MyOntology.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/knowledge/MyOWLClass.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/knowledge/MyOWLDataProperty.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/knowledge/MyOWLObjectProperty.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/knowledge/MyOWLOntology.java
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tool/Util.java)


set(JAVA_JAR_ENTRY_POINT owl2gdb/OWL2GDB)

add_jar(owl2gdb ${SOURCE})

    add_custom_command(TARGET owl2gdb
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND jar u0fm owl2gdb.jar ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ${SOURCE}
    )
```

In my root directory, I do:

> mkdir _build
>
> cd _build
>
> cmake ..
>
> make

*owl2gdb.jar* is indeed generated in *_build/owl2gdb/owl2gdb.jar*. Then

> cd owl2gdb
>
> java -jar owl2gdb.jar

gives me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/martiansoftware/jsap/StringParser

Basically, the external jars are not included in my *owl2gdb.jar*. I don't really know where to go from here. Is there a problem with cmake not properly using CMAKE_JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH? What is missing in my CMakeLists.txt?

a `jar tf owl2gdb.jar` returns:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
tool/Util.class
graphdatabase/GraphDatabase$1.class
graphdatabase/GraphDatabase.class
cpp/CPPFileWriter.class
cpp/GraphDatabaseHeaderWriter.class
cpp/CppHeaderFileWriter.class
cpp/CppTextTemplate.class
cpp/CppSourceFileWriter.class
cpp/GraphDatabaseSourceWriter.class
owl2gdb/OWL2GDB.class
knowledge/MyOWLClass.class
knowledge/MyOWLDataProperty.class
knowledge/MyOntology.class
knowledge/MyOWLObjectProperty.class
knowledge/MyOWLOntology.class
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/OWL2GDB.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/graphdatabase/GraphDatabase.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/CPPFileWriter.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/CppHeaderFileWriter.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/CppSourceFileWriter.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/CppTextTemplate.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/GraphDatabaseHeaderWriter.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/cpp/GraphDatabaseSourceWriter.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/knowledge/MyOntology.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/knowledge/MyOWLClass.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/knowledge/MyOWLDataProperty.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/knowledge/MyOWLObjectProperty.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/knowledge/MyOWLOntology.java
usr/local/me/github/croco/owl2gdb/src/owl2gdb/src/tool/Util.java
```

This is the only thing I have in my manifest:

```
Main-Class: owl2gdb.OWL2GDB
```

Comment: Instead of CMake, use tools that are built for java, like ivy, ant etc..

Comment: @cantSleepNow CMake has these functions already. I just want to learn how to use them properly. I managed to achieve my goal with ANT. I just want to understand what is missing in my CMakeLists.txt.